# ScrollView text alignment SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a vertical `ScrollView` with a `ForEach` loop that has `HStack`'s inside with `Text`, `Image`, and Two `Text`'s. I'd like to keep each row's items in alignment with each other. I've attempted to wrap in a `VStack` with `alignment .leading` but did nothing. The issue I'm having is the text doesn't line up. Still very new to SwiftUI so any help would be appreciated.

[image: Issue]

```swift
ScrollView(.vertical) {
    ForEach(self.daily.forecast, id: \.date) { forecast in
        HStack (spacing : 10){
            Text(forecast.date ?? "")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Spacer()
            RequestImage(Url("IMAGE_URL"))
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .clipped()
            Spacer()
            Text("\(forecast.maxTemp)")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Text("\(forecast.minTemp)")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
    }
}
.padding(.all, 15)
.onAppear() {
    authorize {_ in
        loadForecast()
    }
}
```

UPDATED:
I was able to get a bit closer but things still aren't aligned to where I'd like them to be.

```swift
ScrollView(.vertical) {
    ForEach(self.daily.forecast, id: \.date) { forecast in
        HStack (spacing : 10){
            Text(date)
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .frame(minWidth: 45)
            Spacer()
            RequestImage(Url("IMAGE_URL"))
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                .frame(minWidth: 50)
                .clipped()
            Spacer()
            Text(maxTemp)
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .frame(minWidth: 45)
            Text(minTemp)
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                .frame(minWidth: 45)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
}
.padding(.all, 15)
.onAppear() {
    authorize {_ in
        loadForecast()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's because each of your Text() is a different length. I would suggest setting the width or minWidth on each Text's frame.

Comment: It is not clear how do you want them to be aligned? Would you add some demo/sketch/mock-up?

Comment: @Asperi I added a demo of what I'm looking for with the code. I was close but still looks very off and wrong for the alignment.

Comment: @nicksarno it did help but did not solve my problem

Comment: @Cole add a .background() with a color to each of the items in the HStack and you'll be able to see where the frames are different sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible solution. Prepared with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoWeatherLayout: View {
    private var dayOfTheWeek = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sut"]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(dayOfTheWeek, id: \.self) {
                    WeatherRowView(day: $0, 
                       icon: ["sun.max", "cloud.sun", "cloud", "cloud.snow"].randomElement()!,
                       low: Array(-5..<0).randomElement()!, 
                       high: Array(1..<15).randomElement()!)
                }
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

struct WeatherRowView: View {
    var day: String
    var icon: String
    var low: Int
    var high: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(day)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Image(systemName: icon)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            HStack {
                Text("+XXº").foregroundColor(.clear)
                    .overlay(Text(String(format: "%+d", low)), alignment: .leading)
                Text("+XXº").foregroundColor(.clear)
                    .overlay(Text(String(format: "%+d", high)), alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions:

- add `alignment` parameter to `HStack`:

  `HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline, spacing: 10) { ... //others options: .top, .center, .firstTextBaseline...`
- Add `minLength` parameter to `Spacer`:

  `Spacer(minLength: 0)` but with spacing: 10 in `HStack` it is a bit redundant. You can remove `spacing: 10` for `Spacer(minLength: 10)`
- Add a `Spacer(minLength: 0)` at the end after `Text("\(forecast.minTemp)").fontWeight(.bold)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to accept **@Asperi** answer as **correct**. The UI has indeed changed since to better fit said labels etc. Appreciate everyone's else. The code is very much ugly but works. Not sure if it's 100% correct.

```swift
HStack (spacing: 10){
    Text(date)
        .font(.title3)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    Spacer()
    RequestImage(Url("IMAGE_URL_HERE"))
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        .frame(minWidth: 55)
        .clipped()
    Spacer()
    Text(maxTemp)
        .font(.title3)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .frame(minWidth: 50)
        .background(Color.orange)
        .cornerRadius(5)
    Text(minTemp)
        .font(.title3)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .frame(minWidth: 50)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .cornerRadius(5)
}
```

[image]